How to cascade delete self-relation in Prisma with mongodb
Question
It is written in the doc that we need to set NoAction on self-relation database but how are we supposed to delete the relation then ?
I tried getting all ids and using a deleteMany to delete parent and children together but I got a PrismaClientKnownRequestError.
How to reproduce (optional)

Create self-relation
Try to delete a parent with their children

Expected behavior
We should be able to delete the IDs if I got all the relations
Information about Prisma Schema, Client Queries and Environment
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mongodb"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Tag {
  id           String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name         String
  Parent       Tag?     @relation("Children", fields: [parentId], references: [id], onUpdate: NoAction, onDelete: NoAction)
  parentId     String?  @db.ObjectId
  Children     Tag[]    @relation("Children")
}

async function getAllChildren(
  prisma: PrismaClient,
  tag?: Prisma.TagGetPayload<object>
): Promise<Prisma.TagGetPayload<object>[]> {
  if (!tag) return [];
  const childrenTags = await prisma.tag.findMany({
    where: { parentId: tag.id },
  });
  const subTags = (
    await Promise.all(childrenTags.map((tag) => getAllChildren(prisma, tag)))
  ).flat();

  return [tag, ...subTags];
}

const allTags = await getAllChildren(
prisma,
await prisma.tag.findUnique({
  where: { id: request.params.tagId },
})
);

const tagsIds = allTags.map((t) => t.id);
return prisma.tag.deleteMany({
where: {
  id: { in: tagsIds },
},
});


OS: ArchLinux
Database: MongoDB in docker
Node.js version: 20.11.1

Environment variables loaded from .env
prisma                  : 5.11.0
@prisma/client          : 5.11.0
Computed binaryTarget   : debian-openssl-1.0.x
Operating System        : linux
Architecture            : x64
Node.js                 : v20.11.1
Query Engine (Node-API) : libquery-engine efd2449663b3d73d637ea1fd226bafbcf45b3102 (at ../../node_modules/@prisma/engines/libquery_engine-debian-openssl-1.0.x.so.node)
Schema Engine           : schema-engine-cli efd2449663b3d73d637ea1fd226bafbcf45b3102 (at ../../node_modules/@prisma/engines/schema-engine-debian-openssl-1.0.x)
Schema Wasm             : @prisma/prisma-schema-wasm 5.11.0-15.efd2449663b3d73d637ea1fd226bafbcf45b3102
Default Engines Hash    : efd2449663b3d73d637ea1fd226bafbcf45b3102
Studio                  : 0.499.0

